# Solving Functions with Gekko in Python

Tags: python, gekko

I am looking at using gekko to solve optimisation of time based financial analysis, have been doing this with brute force looping but that is arduous especially as the number of variables becomes more complex.
This is a very simple example of what I am trying to do:
The function ema_cross_strat(x1,x2) calculates the two emas for the timeseries (that could also be passed but isn't currently) then determines if the fast ema is above the slow ema and calculates the return for the time series based on that position.

Is there a way of doing this in Gekko so you could optimise the best moving average combination for the fast and slow averages.?

```
closes['SPY'].tail()
 
date
2021-07-22    434.069275
2021-07-23    438.534973
2021-07-26    439.611511
2021-07-27    437.607941
2021-07-28    437.428497
Name: SPY, dtype: float32

def ema_cross_strat(x1,x2):
    f=x1
    s=x2

    ts = closes['SPY']
    ema_fast = ts.ewm(span = f).mean()
    ema_slow = ts.ewm(span = s).mean()
    strat_position = (ema_fast > ema_slow).astype(float)
       
    strategy = ts.pct_change() * strat_position.shift()
    equity = (strategy+1).cumprod()[-1]

    return -equity

#initialise model
m = GEKKO()

# Integer constraints for x1 and x2
#x1 is the fast EMA, x2 is the slow ema
x1 = m.Var(value=3,lb=3,ub=30,integer=True)
x2 = m.Var(value=30,lb=30,ub=200,integer=True)

#Equations
#slow ema needs to be higher than the fast ema.
m.Equation(x2-x1>0)
#m.Equation(x1**2+x2**2+x3**2+x4**2==eq)
#Objective
m.Minimize(ema_cross_strat(x1,x2))
#Set global options
m.Minimize(f(x))
m.options.SOLVER=1
m.solve()
```

this currently generates an error which suggests the variables are not being passed correctly but I am not clear why based on other examples, or if this type of thing works at all with gekko. have tried passing just x with an array for x1,x2 but the result is the same.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-76-6fa879b27b94> in <module>
     12 
     13 #Objective
---> 14 m.Minimize(ema_cross_strat(x1,x2))
     15 #Set global options
     16 m.Minimize(f(x))

<ipython-input-71-caf179a766b9> in ema_cross_strat(x1, x2)
      4 
      5     ts = closes['SPY']
----> 6     ema_fast = ts.ewm(span = f).mean()
      7     ema_slow = ts.ewm(span = s).mean()
      8     strat_position = (ema_fast > ema_slow).astype(float)

C:\Anaconda3\envs\env_zip36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in ewm(self, com, span, halflife, alpha, min_periods, freq, adjust, ignore_na, axis)
   7084             return rwindow.ewm(self, com=com, span=span, halflife=halflife,
   7085                                alpha=alpha, min_periods=min_periods, freq=freq,
-> 7086                                adjust=adjust, ignore_na=ignore_na, axis=axis)
   7087 
   7088         cls.ewm = ewm

C:\Anaconda3\envs\env_zip36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\window.py in ewm(obj, **kwds)
   2087         raise TypeError('invalid type: %s' % type(obj))
   2088 
-> 2089     return EWM(obj, **kwds)
   2090 
   2091 

C:\Anaconda3\envs\env_zip36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\window.py in __init__(self, obj, com, span, halflife, alpha, min_periods, freq, adjust, ignore_na, axis)
   1682                  axis=0):
   1683         self.obj = obj
-> 1684         self.com = _get_center_of_mass(com, span, halflife, alpha)
   1685         self.min_periods = min_periods
   1686         self.freq = freq

C:\Anaconda3\envs\env_zip36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\window.py in _get_center_of_mass(com, span, halflife, alpha)
   1986             raise ValueError("com must satisfy: com >= 0")
   1987     elif span is not None:
-> 1988         if span < 1:
   1989             raise ValueError("span must satisfy: span >= 1")
   1990         com = (span - 1) / 2.

C:\Anaconda3\envs\env_zip36\lib\site-packages\gekko\gk_operators.py in __len__(self)
     23         return self.name
     24     def __len__(self):
---> 25         return len(self.value)
     26     def __getitem__(self,key):
     27         return self.value[key]

C:\Anaconda3\envs\env_zip36\lib\site-packages\gekko\gk_operators.py in __len__(self)
    142 
    143     def __len__(self):
--> 144         return len(self.value)
    145 
    146     def __getitem__(self,key):

TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

Answer (score 2):

Gekko creates the model once and then passes it to a solver. Any functions need to be defined in a way that the problem is symbolically expressed so that it doesn't require re-evaluation. One thing to try is `Scipy.optimize.minimize()` and create some way of making the decision variables continuous (such as an average with only a fraction of the next number). Here is information on [Scipy.optimize.minimize and Gekko for optimization](https://apmonitor.com/che263/index.php/Main/PythonOptimization).

**Scipy**

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def objective(x):
    return x[0]*x[3]*(x[0]+x[1]+x[2])+x[2]

def constraint1(x):
    return x[0]*x[1]*x[2]*x[3]-25.0

def constraint2(x):
    sum_eq = 40.0
    for i in range(4):
        sum_eq = sum_eq - x[i]**2
    return sum_eq

# initial guesses
n = 4
x0 = np.zeros(n)
x0[0] = 1.0
x0[1] = 5.0
x0[2] = 5.0
x0[3] = 1.0

# show initial objective
print('Initial Objective: ' + str(objective(x0)))

# optimize
b = (1.0,5.0)
bnds = (b, b, b, b)
con1 = {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': constraint1} 
con2 = {'type': 'eq', 'fun': constraint2}
cons = ([con1,con2])
solution = minimize(objective,x0,method='SLSQP',\
                    bounds=bnds,constraints=cons)
x = solution.x

# show final objective
print('Final Objective: ' + str(objective(x)))

# print solution
print('Solution')
print('x1 = ' + str(x[0]))
print('x2 = ' + str(x[1]))
print('x3 = ' + str(x[2]))
print('x4 = ' + str(x[3]))
```

**Gekko**

```py
from gekko import GEKKO    
import numpy as np

#Initialize Model
m = GEKKO()

#help(m)

#define parameter
eq = m.Param(value=40)

#initialize variables
x1,x2,x3,x4 = [m.Var(lb=1,ub=5) for i in range(4)]

#initial values
x1.value = 1
x2.value = 5
x3.value = 5
x4.value = 1

m.Equation(x1*x2*x3*x4>=25)
m.Equation(x1**2+x2**2+x3**2+x4**2==eq)

m.Minimize(x1*x4*(x1+x2+x3)+x3)

m.solve()

print('Results')
print('x1: ' + str(x1.value))
print('x2: ' + str(x2.value))
print('x3: ' + str(x3.value))
print('x4: ' + str(x4.value))
```

If you wanted to use Gekko, consider making a continuous function from the averages to [create a cubic spline (cspline)](https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Main/ObjectCspline) from the relationship between average and number of values.